# How to find prebid account server id and ad config_id in own prebid server?

Tags: prebid.js, prebid, prebinding

```
PrebidMobile.setPrebidServerAccountId("123456");
PrebidMobile.setCustomStatusEndpoint("http://example.com:8080/status");
PrebidMobile.setPrebidServerHost(
Host.createCustomHost(
"http://example.com:8080/openrtb2/auction"
)
)
```

Mentioned above server_account_id is not work. From my domain, where to find server_account_id the above ids and also need more detail about the below IDs and where to find and use.

private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "/21808260008/prebid_demo_app_original_api_banner";
private static final String CONFIG_ID = "prebid-ita-banner-320-50";

Where ids are configured and how to get and use it in android native applications.